# Give name to a file within a zip archive which generated from stdout

Tags: bash, postgresql, gzip

I am running a postgresql query in a python script

```
copy (SELECT * FROM table) TO PROGRAM 'gzip > ./" + file_from + "' with csv HEADER;
```

The generated zip file has the expected name, but the file inside the zip archive does not have extension, it has the same as the zipfile minus the ".zip" extension. I would like to add the ".csv" extension to the filename without doing complex operations (e.g. unzip, rename, zip).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: gzip is not zip. zip is not gzip. A gzip file is not an archive -- it is just one file compressed. gzip does not add a ".zip" extension. It adds ".gz". Your question does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gzip does not create an archive like pkzip does.

If you send gzip's output to `datadump.csv.gz` then running `gunzip` against it will decompress it to a file named `datadump.csv`, but that is just a convenience feature that follows a convention and has no impact on what is actually inside the file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to use "gzip", the convention will be to create use ".csv.gz" as a suffix. Using "gunzip" on the file will result in filename.csv.

If the above example, set file_name to "whatever.csv.gz"

Using ZIP format is a little more complex, as zip works better with files. The equivalent command will be `zip whatever.zip -` to compress, and 'funzip whatever.zip > whatever.csv' to uncomrpess